# Debezium source task fails to reconnect to postgresql DB when DB container is re-created

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, kubernetes, debezium

We have a kubernetes cluster with Debezium running as a source task from a Postgresql and writing to kafka. Debezium, postgres and kafka are all running in separate pods.
When the postgres pod is deleted and kubernetes re-creates the pod, debezium pod fails to re-connect.
Logs from debezium pod:

```
    2018-07-17 08:31:38,311 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=inventory-connector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
    2018-07-17 08:31:38,311 INFO   ||  [Producer clientId=producer-4] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer]
```

Debezium continues to try to flush outstanding messages at intervals, but gives the following exception:

```
    2018-07-17 08:32:38,167 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=inventory-connector-0} Exception thrown while calling task.commit()   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask]
    org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Database connection failed when writing to copy
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.RecordsStreamProducer.commit(RecordsStreamProducer.java:151)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.commit(PostgresConnectorTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.commitSourceTask(WorkerSourceTask.java:437)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSourceTask.java:378)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.commit(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.access$000(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter$1.run(SourceTaskOffsetCommitter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Database connection failed when writing to copy
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.flushCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:942)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyDualImpl.flushCopy(CopyDualImpl.java:23)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.updateStatusInternal(V3PGReplicationStream.java:176)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.forceUpdateStatus(V3PGReplicationStream.java:99)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection$1.doFlushLsn(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:246)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection$1.flushLsn(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:239)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.RecordsStreamProducer.commit(RecordsStreamProducer.java:146)
    ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.flush(PGStream.java:553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.flushCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:939)
    ... 19 more
```

Is there a way to have debezium re-establish its connection to postgres when it becomes available?
Or am I missing some config?

- Debezium version 0.8
- kubernetes version 1.10.3
- postgres version 9.6

Comment: Can you share more details regarding kubernetes, for example yaml files? It would be helpful if you provided more details regarding the environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a common issue and has open feature requests in both debezium and kafka

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-248

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5352

While these are open, it looks like this is expected behaviour

As a workaround I've add this liveness probe to the deployment

```
    livenessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
          - sh
          - -ec
          - ipaddress=$(ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/'); reply=$(curl -s $ipaddress:8083/connectors/inventory-connector/status | grep -o RUNNING | wc -l); if [ $reply -lt 2 ]; then exit 1; fi;
        initialDelaySeconds: 30
        periodSeconds: 5
```

First clause gets the container IP address:

```
    ipaddress=$(ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d'/');
```

Second clause makes the request and counts instances of 'RUNNING' in the response json:

```
    reply=$(curl -s $ipaddress:8083/connectors/inventory-connector/status | grep -o RUNNING | wc -l);
```

Third clause returns exit code 1 if 'RUNNING' appears less than twice

```
    if [ $reply -lt 2 ]; then exit 1; fi
```

It seems to be working on initial tests - i.e. restarting the postgres DB triggers a restart of the debezium container. I guess a script something like this (although perhaps 'robustified') could be included in the image to facilitate the probe.

Comment: Hey, yes, currently we don't have any notion of re-connecting implemented within the connectors themselves. The idea being, that this can be done by an orchestration layer (Kubernetes in your case), which would monitor the connector status via the REST API and restart if the task goes to FAILED. This is not set in stone, though, and we may end up providing an internal solution, too, but we didn't get to it yet.

Comment: Ok thanks @Gunnar. Good to know that I'm not missing something and that this is expected. I'll try to add kubernetes liveness and readiness probes to the Debezium pod to handle this scenario.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be the idea. You can fetch the connector status from the Kafka Connect REST API from an URL like this: http://connect-host:8083/connectors/your-connector/status. That being said, if you manage to implement said probe, perhaps you'd be interested in writing a guest post on the topic on the blog on debezium.io? It surely would be helpful to other folks, too.

Comment: @Gunnar - looks like that api returns 200 OK both when the task is RUNNING and when it is FAILED. kubelet relies on the status code to determine whether the pod is live/ready or not. Maybe it's possible to execute a command and parse the json response - I'll give it a go

Comment: You could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to retrieve the exact task state: curl -s $ipaddress:8083/connectors/hiking-connector/status | jq '.tasks[0].state'

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind with the liveness probe approach is that AFAIU it'll restart the entire Kafka Connect node. This might not be ideal when deploying multiple connectors to a single instance (just in case you're doing that).

Comment: You mean when debezium is connected to more than one source? E.g. multiple databases? If so, then yes, this approach is not suitable as kubernetes does restart the container that hosts the debezium application. In our case there is only one source so far. 
Perhaps another reason to consider handling task restarts internally?

Comment: 5 years later did you find any better alternative ?

Comment: @jonathanChevalier I asked again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78033460/debezium-fails-to-reconenct-after-lost-connection-to-db/78033632#78033632